# Android application crashes when trying to click button

Tags: android, kotlin

Hello i tried to write a hangman game in kotlin but when i click button application crashes. It might be bad kotlin syntax or something. Logcat tells me that it's error in this function

```
    private fun showLetter(char: Char) {
        val tv = tvWord.text.toString().toCharArray()
        for (i in tv.indices) {
            if (keyWord[i] == char) tv[i] = char
        }
        tvWord.text = String(tv)
    }
```

At this line

```
if (keyWord[i] == char) tv[i] = char
```

Comment: Check and post (if you need help) the stacktrace

Comment: check the exception stack trace for more info

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unfortunately MyApp has stopped. How can I solve this?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23353173/unfortunately-myapp-has-stopped-how-can-i-solve-this)

Comment: Posting the whole class should help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It must be an array out of bound exception.

tv is larger than keyword, so requesting keyword[i] when i is too big triggers an error.

Depending on what you want to do, check the length of both arrays before your loop, change the values on which your i variable increments, or `break` your loop when a condition is met.